# I am trying to connect to databricks through cli, wated to replicate same in Azure devops

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, databricks

In the local system i am writing commands:
*pip install databricks-cli
databricks configure--token*
token value and later token

Now the thing is In azure devops i am using task cli and in that i have to enter the code but the catch is in local when code is running then i have to give the token and workspace but in azure devops i have to give in code only.

so is there is any way how to do this i have wriiten this code but its failing:
[the pic from azure devops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwBj6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of configure we tend to write the configuration straight to the ~/.databrickscfg

```
echo "
[DEFAULT]
host = ...
token = ...
" > ~/.databrickscfg
```